# Reducing 3D dataset size for python coding

Tags: python, data-science, binning

I have 11 hdf5 files each of 500 MB, thus a total of 5.5 GB worth of data.

I need to plot this data into a 3D scatter plot.

However, due to the large size of the dataset, the code is taking forever to load.

Is there a python library or method to reduce the dataset size without any loss of data for easy plotting?

Comment: What do you mean by *reduce the dataset size without any loss*? Is not that contradiction?

Comment: do u mean dimension reduction?

Comment: What you want might be impossible. But maybe you are loading the data in an inefficient manner. Can you share the code that loads the data?

Comment: I mean to reduce the data dimension / pack chunks of data in statistical bins to process faster. Please see my question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625043/creating-bins-from-3d-points-large-dataset-with-python-for-faster-processing